# How do I protect Dynamic data pages using ASP.NET Authentication?

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication, dynamic-data

I have a site where most of my pages are arranged in business area folders, e.g. *Activations, Outdoors, Branding*.  Each folder has a small web.config that protects the contents against access by people without a role for that business area.

However, basic admin for most business areas is done via Dynamic Data pages.  These are only basically protected by not appearing in the menu unless the user has the correct role, but they are still accessible directly via URL, because of the {table}/{Action} routing used by Dynamic Data.  What can I do to protect these pages against direct access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The forum post by 'sjnaughton' (second down from the top of the page) may help you:

http://forums.asp.net/t/1343958.aspx

HTH,

Richard.

Comment: Naughton is a Dynamic Data God.